# Realm and iOS Retain Cycles

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

Does realm properly handle entities that have a parent-child relationship (e.g. the child holds a reference to the parent)? The documentation states that Realm ignores the property modifiers (nonatomic, weak, ...), so I basically don't have control of this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For standalone objects (i.e. objects created with `[[MyClass alloc] init]` which have not been added to a Realm afterwards) the normal rules apply, and you'll need to use a `weak` property to break the retain cycle if you're constructing graphs of standalone objects.

For objects persisted in a Realm, accessing `RLMObject`-subclass properties actually creates a new object each time rather than caching the accessor object. This means that the objects never actually hold references to any other in-memory objects, so there can't be a retain cycle.